# Can you set an ALB from a different account as a Target of an ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are looking to forward traffic from an Application Load Balancer to another Load Balancer on a different account.

So lets say:

ALB (Account A) -> Target Group (Account A) -> ALB (Account B)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot target the ALB in Account B directly. You could have target instances living in Account B and use the `ip` [target type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type), assuming those instances are routable from Account A though VPC Peering.

AWS has a pretty good blog on the topic of [ALB routing by IP](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancing-via-ip-address-to-aws-on-premises-resources/). You can also use this approach to use your ALB with servers hosted outside of AWS.

If you really want another ALB in between (i.e. in Account B), you could probably do that by deploying some kind of reverse proxy (like Nginx or Kong) in Account A behind your ALB, which could pass traffic through to Account B.

Comment: Manually targeting instances might not be ideal in my use case. Instances are dynamically scaled and managed via ECS. So we don't really manage the IPs. Any recommendations?

Comment: Yeah, put something in front that is intended to serve as a gateway to your APIs like Kong, API Gateway, or a simple Nginx service. ALB wasn't designed to do what you want. You can do AccountA:ALB --> AccountA:Target Group --> AccountA:Nginx (ECS Container) --> AccountB:ALB --> AccountB:TargetGroup --> AccountB:Services